# How to multiply two columns of a pandas data-frame (row multiplication) and store the result in a new column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Command

`df_main['Ranking'] = df_main['Porosity']*['Permeability']` gives -

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

The attacehd picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Asu3.png) has more information. My code snippet is at i.stack.imgur.com/ehqF5.png)

More info: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Asu3.png

Comment: Did you try `df_main['Ranking'] = df_main['Porosity']*df_main['Permeability']`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to convert the column type of the two columns to floats (otherwise you cannot multiply them). You can do that as follows:

```
df_main[['Porosity', 'Permeability']] = df_main[['Porosity', 'Permeability']].astype(float)
```

Then you can define the new column via multiplication:

```
df_main['Ranking'] = df_main['Porosity']*df_main['Permeability']
```

Comment: I'm not so sure the `.astype(float)` step is needed. I think the problem was they were trying to multiply the column by a single-element list containing only a string.

Comment: @SethMMorton in the imgur figure in the question the syntax of the product seems correct.

Comment: When I tried corrected form of Miriam's answer, I got the following error Value Error: could not convert string to float: '12.863486     2'

Comment: @Czar.Wolfgang based on the error " Value Error: could not convert string to float: '12.863486 2" you have somewhere in one of the two columns the value '12.863486 2". This indeed cannot be converted to float because it is not a real number as you have a space before the 2. You need to decide what to do with such non-numeric entries. You cannot just multiply non-numeric numbers. You need to decide whether it is a nan, or whether you want to convert it to float somehow.

Comment: Oh yes, I checked. You are correct @MiriamFarber I cannot consider them as NaN, do you know anyway to convert such values to float?

Comment: @Czar.Wolfgang It depends on how you want to do that. If you just want to remove the white spaces (that is, concatenate the 2 to the rest of the number in the case such as the one in the error) you can do: df_main[['Porosity', 'Permeability']]=df_main[['Porosity', 'Permeability']].replace(" ","", regex=True). This should be done before the lines that appear in my answer (that is, after you do that, you can continue with the rest of the lines in the answer).