# multyply all values in dataframe by a column

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe df,

```
item 1   item 2   item3   item4  values
  1        0        1      1       10
  0        1        0      1       22
  ...
```

How can get,

```
item1   item2   item3    item4   
  10      0       10       10
  0       22       0        22
```

Thanks!

Comment: If values is part of the dataframe, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155063/how-to-multiply-two-columns-of-a-pandas-data-frame-row-multiplication-and-stor

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df.iloc[:,0:4] = df.iloc[:,0:4].multiply(df.iloc[:,4].values, axis=0)
```

example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3,4), columns=list('abcd'))
print(df)

df.iloc[:,0:3] = df.iloc[:,0:3].multiply(df.iloc[:,3].values, axis=0)

print(df)
```

output:

```
   a  b   c   d
0  0  1   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11


    a   b    c   d
0   0   3    6   3
1  28  35   42   7
2  88  99  110  11
```